# What happens in case of temporary HS guard unavailability?

Tags: onion-services, guard-node, guard

In my Tor testing environment I noticed that if a HS guard node is unavailable, it is not immediately replaced by using another guard.

I know that entry guards are changed after months (6-9?) but I am wondering what happens if a guard becomes unavailable before that period. Is another guard selected as entry guard for the hidden service? If yes, how long after does the new guard is selected? I expect that if the guard is temporarily unavailable, it can still play the role of guard of that HS if it is back online within a certain amount of time. If yes? How much is this amount of time.

Thanks a lot,
Lewis